# How to install pgAdmin

Tags: pgadmin

I use Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit.
At first I installed pgAdmin through Software Center. But it seemed old. So, I decided to 
uninstal it.

Then I downloaded graphic installer for PostgresQL.

```
sudo ./postgresql-9.2.1-1-linux-x64.run
```

I was warned that a previous version of pgAdmin is found, it will be upgraded but I'll have to restart the server.

Well, installation process worked. Then I turned out in terminal again.

I restarted the server

```
/etc/init.d$ sudo ./postgresql-9.2 restart


/opt/PostgreSQL/9.2/pgAdmin3/bin$ ./pgadmin3
```

The answer is:

```
The program 'pgadmin3' is currently not installed.
```

So, I can't find my pgAdmin to launch it. Could you suggest me anything?

Answer (score 1):

download last from official source http://www.pgadmin.org/download/source.php

```
sudo aptitude install postgresql postgresql-server-dev-9.2  postgresql-9.2-dbg libalien-wxwidgets-perl plplot11-driver-wxwidgets libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev

./configure
make
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
```

With a newer version you lose the advantage of having updates "sanctioned" by the community.

However if you need the latest pgadmin3 that works with PostgreSQL 9.2 you need to:

```
sudo apt-get remove pgadmin3 -- remove it if already installed
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:voronov84/andreyv
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
```

Taken from [here](http://linuxrails.blogspot.com/2012/09/install-pgadmin-for-postgresql-92-on.html).

Comment: I'm new to Ubuntu. Maybe your argument is reasonable. But I already did this step through GUI. Then I removed what was installed. I decided that the newest release is better for me. Then there is a learning shade. I have come across a difficulty, then it is interesting for me how to break through. Maybe you could suggest me what I dit wrongly?

Comment: @Kifsif Edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Well, I'll try that but not this time. Nowadays I would like to find out what i did wrongly and how to proceed. I don't want to remove the program. It may have installed correctly. But somehow I can't find it. Could you help me?

Comment: can third party repos like these be trusted? or should we stick with either building source or installing the older version from the ubuntu repo